# Creating an X amount of rectangles which are not intersecting each other on a specified screen size

Tags: c++, graphics, geometry, sdl

I managed with some help to know how when two rectangles are intersecting each other, from there it should be easy to make what i just said in the title but ...

So, short story of what i just did below:
Created a for loop from 1 to Number_of_Obstacles
In that for an random obstacle (rectangle/square) is created and it will be checked if it is overlaped with all other obstacles created from 0 to the loop contor (or in other words every obstacle stored in the vector)

Again, the doOverLap function works. Tested it with a square which i made a controller and other random rectangle created on the screen. It outputs in chat when i'm overlaping it and trust me, i overlaped it from all angles.

Here is a picture with the overlaping issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJnxV.jpg

```
bool doOverlap(A a, B b)
{
    if (a.x1 > b.x2 || b.x1 > a.x2)
        return false;
    if (a.y1 > b.y2 || b.y1 > a.y2)
        return false;
    return true;
}

struct Obstacles {
    int X, Y;
void Create_Random_Obstacles(Obstacles Obj[], int Numar_Obstacole)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    A Rectangle_1;
    B Rectangle_2;

    /* To avoid rendering outside of the screen */
    int X_Axis = X_RESOLUTION - 40;
    int Y_Axis = Y_RESOLUTION - 40;

    int obstacolX = rand() % X_Axis + 1;
    int obstacolY = rand() % Y_Axis + 1;

    Obj[0].X = obstacolX;
    Obj[0].Y = obstacolY;

    for (int i = 1; i < Numar_Obstacole; i++)
    {
        obstacolX = rand() % X_Axis + 1;
        obstacolY = rand() % Y_Axis + 1;

        Rectangle_1.x1 = obstacolX;
        Rectangle_1.x2 = obstacolX + 40;
        Rectangle_1.y1 = obstacolY;
        Rectangle_1.y2 = obstacolY + 40;

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            Rectangle_2.x1 = Obj[j].X;
            Rectangle_2.x2 = Obj[j].X + 40;
            Rectangle_2.y1 = Obj[j].Y;
            Rectangle_2.y2 = Obj[j].Y + 40;

            if (doOverlap(Rectangle_1, Rectangle_2))
            {
                std::cout << "Overlap\n";
            }
            else
            {
                Obj[i].X = obstacolX;
                Obj[i].Y = obstacolY;
            }
        }   
    }
}

void Render(SDL_Renderer* renderer, Obstacles Obj[], int Numar_Obstacole) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Numar_Obstacole; i++) 
    {
        SDL_Rect r{ Obj[i].X, Obj[i].Y, 40, 40 };
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 160, 15, 255);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &r);
    }
}
```

};

Comment: Due to the nature of randomness, it is possible to end up in situations where you cannot place any more rectangles. In that case just start over.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a physics-based spring simulation to spread out the boxes and prevent them from overlapping.

Comment: your code only checks if the two rectangls you are about to add overlap, but you need to check for collision between any rectangles

Comment: well no not really, the problem is that I don't understand your code at all :/

Comment: There are 2 loops, in first loop is created an rectangle and when the second loop is on, all existing obstacles are checked for overlaping with the previous created rectangle (from first loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart selection when collision occurs, something like:

```
bool Has_Overlap(const Obstacles& obj, const Obstacles* Objs, int Size)
{
    B Rectangle_2;
    Rectangle_2.x1 = obs.X;
    Rectangle_2.x2 = obs.X + 40;
    Rectangle_2.y1 = obs.Y;
    Rectangle_2.y2 = obs.Y + 40;
    for (int i = 0; i != Size; ++i) {
        A Rectangle_1;
        Rectangle_1.x1 = Obs[i].X;
        Rectangle_1.x2 = Obs[i].X + 40;
        Rectangle_1.y1 = Obs[i].Y;
        Rectangle_1.y2 = Obs[i].Y + 40;
        if (doOverlap(Rectangle_1, Rectangle_2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void Create_Random_Obstacles(Obstacles* Objs, int Size)
{
    /* To avoid rendering outside of the screen */
    const int X_Axis = X_RESOLUTION - 40;
    const int Y_Axis = Y_RESOLUTION - 40;

    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        do {
            Objs[i].X = rand() % X_Axis + 1;
            Objs[i].Y = rand() % Y_Axis + 1;
        } while (Has_Overlap(Objs[i], Objs, i));
    }
}
```